.py file is not a valid Win32 application error
I am trying to run a .py script with the Runas command but I get the following error:
193: C:\temp\module1.py is not a valid Win32 application.

My command is:
runas /user:domain\username "C:\temp\module1.py"

I am unsure why this error is being thrown and every SO post I have read has not helped.
What exactly does this message mean and how could I resolve it?

Python files are not directly executable.  You have to run python.exe and pass the script name as an argument.

@JohnGordon are you saying something like this: runas /user:domain\username C:\path\to\exe "C:\temp\module1.py"

Yes, that should work.

I have no experience with runas, but based on your current command,
Try either
runas /user:domain\username python "C:\temp\module1.py"
Or
runas /user:domain\username /path/to/python.exe "C:\temp\module1.py"
Make sure you have installed python.

@john-gordon speaks correctly. Alternatively, if you won't use Python interpreter, you may use pyinstaller for building standalone executable with pyinstaller -F your_python_script.py command after installation it.
